# .prop("checked", false) doesn't work perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, prop

In order to uncheck a radio button with Jquery...

I use this code :

```
$('input[type=radio][name=belvg_customerattributes_particulier]:checked').prop("checked", false);
```

This code works but visualy I still see the button on checked.

I tried this :

```
$('input[type=radio][name=belvg_customerattributes_particulier]:checked').prop("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

But in vain..

Please help me !

Comment: What is `checkboxradio("refresh")` ?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Hi, I use jQuery 1.11. About checkboxradio("refresh"), I don't know I have found it on this forum...

Comment: refresh()
Refreshes the visual state of the widget. Useful for updating after the native element's checked or disabled state is changed programmatically.

But doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

So it works... I have investigated and I have seen a class before the imput.

So my radio was checked but not visualy.

For your information I have added code to remove the class in this span with :

```
$("#uniform-belvg_customerattributes_particulier_0 span.checked").toggleClass("checked");
```

Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Please use
$(‘#checkbox’).prop(‘checked’, false).uniform(); 
I don’t know exactly how it works. But it works for me to uncheck the checkbox.